# How to merge two fields into single field using INNER JOIN

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have two tables.

```
**EmployeeInfo**
   EmployeeName varchar(50)
   EmailAddress varchar(100)
   BranchID     int

**BranchInfo**
   BranchID  int
   opMgr     varchar(100)
   BranchMgr varchar(100)
```

I want a stored procedure in which if I pass email address as parameter and it should display the OpMgr and BranchMgr column from branchinfo table into single column of the relevant branch of EmployeeInfo. I am trying to write the following but no luck as i am getting multipart error.

```
SELECT  BranchInfo.OpMgr FROM  EmployeesInfo 
UNION
SELECT BranchInfo.BranchMgr FROM EmployeesInfo 
INNER JOIN BranchInfo ON EmployeesInfo.BranchID = BranchInfo.BranchID
WHERE AND EMPLOYEESINFO.EMAILADDRESS='john.d@mydomain.com'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> it should display the OpMgr and BranchMgr column from branchinfo table
>   into **single column** of the relevant branch of EmployeeInfo

```
DECLARE @opMgr VARCHAR(100), @BranchMgr VARCHAR(100)

SELECT @opMgr  = b.opMgr, @BranchMgr =  b.BranchMgr
FROM EmployeeInfo e
JOIN BranchInfo b ON e.BranchID = b.BranchID
WHERE e.EMAILADDRESS='john.d@mydomain.com'

SELECT details 
FROM ( VALUES (@opMgr),(@BranchMgr)) 
AS t(details)
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
SELECT
    E.EmployeeName,
    E.EmailAddress,
    B.BranchID,
    B.BranchMgr + ' ' + B.opMgr ColName
FROM EmployeesInfo E
    INNER JOIN BranchInfo B
        ON E.BranchID = B.BranchID
WHERE E.EMAILADDRESS='john.d@mydomain.com'
```

Answer (score 1):

you can have `JOIN` like this

```
SELECT b.opMgr + b.BranchMgr as Branch
FROM EmployeeInfo e
JOIN BranchInfo b ON b.BranchID = BranchID
WHERE e.EMAILADDRESS='john.d@mydomain.com'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
SELECT BranchInfo.OpMgr, BranchInfo.BranchMgr
  FROM EmployeesInfo
 INNER JOIN BranchInfo ON EmployeesInfo.BranchID = BranchInfo.BranchID
 WHERE AND EMPLOYEESINFO.EMAILADDRESS = 'john.d@mydomain.com'
```

Comment: Oops. Edited it now to mysql syntax.

Comment: Guys, Merging column values is not what I am looking for..it should come as two rows but with column...

Comment: @user342944 The title suggested merging and hence the sql query. Anyways, have edited the answer. Check and let me know if this is what you are looking for.